# Option to disable the "Ask a question wizard"

Tags: support, ask-question-wizard-2018

I haven't asked a question since the end of last year.

Now it seems I have to go through a few more hoops in order to get that done, whereas before I was presented directly with a nice, well laid-out screen that presented me with everything I needed to ask a good, well formatted question.

I do see the point of it I think - we want well formatted question to avoid the garbage-in, garbage-out problem that tends to come with bigger and bigger SO.

However, it's frustrating to try to ask a question with it in my experience. A few specifics:

- Shortcuts seems to be disabled? Can't ctrl + l to link stuff quickly it appears. Sure I could still just write it out but why remove the quickest, best way to make a proper link reference?
- Just more clicks to get the same results - as a base principle I do not believe this is an improvement
- Clutter. I have text for my question, but then also a bunch of text from the wizard. It feels harder to make things clearer in my mind than when I have extra content on screen.
- General format. I do see the value in some sort of standardize format for question. However, I don't think that the format provided is the be-all-end-all solution to this. Also, I am skeptical that ALL questions are best formatted in a single manner. I think this is somewhat dependent on the nature of question.

I've been around SO for a while (reading more than asking, but still). I'm pretty sure I can ask a question that contributes positively to the platform without the wizard. In fact, I feel LESS inclined to ask a question now. My hypothesis at this point is that while the wizard might make terrible questions somewhat acceptable instead, it may also turn off more valuable contributers from asking great questions. So I am unsure if, being forced as it currently seems to be, the wizard will actually improve overall question quality.

Could we have some option to turn it off in some fashion?

Comment: But yeah, it's not a dupe in the sense of 'your answer is there'. But it's a dupe in the sense of 'all the info you want or need about the wizard is there, including why you're seeing it, and why you can't turn it off'

Comment: I wanted to bring to the front the idea that we SHOULD be allowed to turn it off. Actually there's very little mentioned about turning it off - the thread is arguably more about hyping it.

Quite possibly you are not stuck with it a the moment, otherwise you may be more emphatic with the question...

Comment: Nice question, and it prompted a very informative answer. Win-win!

Comment: I think this is about the scope of the wizard. The OP has 10 questions that were at least non-negatively received. No obvious terrible questions. Leaving aside any deleted questions I can't see, what's visible in the profile makes the OP unlikely to benefit from the wizard. So, how does SO make the decision to show the wizard? Here is a straw man suggestion: less than  3 questions or 30% of the questions have negative scores or are closed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The wizard takes you through six steps to enter basic information about your question:

1. Tags
2. Title
3. Description: Summary
4. Description: Background
5. Description: Code
6. Description: Results

You have to enter *something* for the first two steps. But you were probably going to do that anyway. You can skip right past all the "Description" sections if you want... That leaves you on the Review screen:

[image: Review your question (the last step of the wizard interface)]

This is essentially the same editor as the one you've used in the past. All the keyboard shortcuts work, you get to see everything on one screen, there's actually *even less clutter* than there is on the normal Ask page. You could, if you wished, skip through the wizard to get to this page pretty fast...

...but maybe you shouldn't. Spend a bit of extra time on those first pages, think carefully about the *content* of the post you're about to make, and then - when you do get to the final Review stage - you can edit it to make it look shiny. This is a tried and true technique for effective writing, and while it doesn't work for everyone I think you might find it surprisingly robust if you gave it a chance.

And if, after giving it a fair shot, you *don't* like it... Well, now you know how to quickly skip it.

Comment: Ouh interesting. And close enough to a one-click ask a question we used to have. Again, I do see the point of it. I just don't like because it makes things (in my view) needlessly detailed and feels somewhat like taking away a command-line & replacing with a UI I never asked for and that ultimately slows me down. I guess that if I had stuck it out until the end I would have known! Thanks.